# eclipse juno error on importing a eclipse indigo project

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, ide, eclipse-indigo, eclipse-juno

Hi folks When I import a project created in eclipse indigo into eclipse juno then my servlet classes are not recognized by eclipse juno and it shows error on all servlet classes like `HTTPServlet` etc.What can I do now? But when I am creating a new dynamic project then servlets are working fine.It means it only unable to find servlet API path when I import any eclipse indigo project.[image]

Comment: the first thing to do would be to show us the error message.

Comment: It shows error (red line under the HTTPServlet) "HTTPServlet cannot be resolved to a type" - It means it is not able to find the Servlet API

Answer (score 0):

Open the project's settings, the "java Build Path" tab. Check if a appropriate runtime library for your servlet container is in the list. I suspect not.

If it is not missing, expand the library and check if there is a servlet.jar or servlet-api.jar.

If it's missing, click the "Add Library..." button, select "server runtime", click next and choose one from the list.

If this list again is empty (probably), you need to configure a server runtime first. To accomplish this, select window, preferences from the eclipse menu, go to "Server", sub menu "Runtime Environment" and add a suitable one. Then add this to your projects build path.

Comment: if you expand the server runtime library in the project properties, libraries tab: does it list a servlet-api.jar?